# Syntax error with ansible playbook code block

Tags: ansible, yaml

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'home_user' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/vagrant/playbook.yml': line 118, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  # TODO duplicated in cell-playbook.yml\n  - name: Trust github.com\n    ^ here\n"}

```
  # TODO duplicated in cell-playbook.yml  
  - name: SSH config file
    copy:
      src: files/ssh_config
      dest: /home/{{ home_user}}/.ssh/config
      owner: "{{ home_user }}"
      group: "{{ home_user }}"
      mode: '0664'
    tags: [ never, cell_deployment]
  # TODO duplicated in cell-playbook.yml
  - name: Trust github.com
    lineinfile:
      path: /home/{{ home_user }}/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Hey everyone I am new to stackoverflow ( my first question ) and programming. Sorry if my question seems vague. I have tried to search through stackoverflow for remedies, however, I haven't found anything thus far that has helped.

My YAML isn't very good but I feel confident that - name: Trust github.com is sound.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

=====
EDIT( march 19th )- responding to Kroustou: Am I defining `home_user` correctly?=====

```
 `---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  tasks:    
  - name: Load variables    
    include_vars: "{{ item }}"
    home_user: "{{home_user}}" 
    with_items:
      - "cell_specific_vars/customer_vaulted.yml"
      - "cell_specific_vars/customer_vars.yml"
      - "cell_specific_vars/cell_vars.yml"
      - "cell_specific_vars/cell_release.yml"`
```

Is this corret? When I run it through a YAML validator it says it's valid, however, when I run my playbook, it says "ERROR! conflicting action statements: home_user, include vars.

I am trying to avoid the error that `home_user` is undefined.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome dtovar. The variable `home_user` has not been defined. Make sure you define that. It can be declared either in one of the roles or the tasks if you need something dynamic, else it can be defined inside `group_vars` and the like. For more information please take a look at the docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html

Comment: Thank you! I am eager to help others with their questions. For now, I am asking them as I begin this new adventure in software development. 

Your answer led me to realize what the over arching issue was. Thank you! 

I have a tasks "Load variables" that were commented out.

Comment: Defining var: Am I able to define the variable home_user anywhere in the playbook? Or does it need to exist prior to it being called?

Comment: I have updated my answer a bit. TLDR No, it has to be defined before you use it. If you define it dynamically it has to be defined before the task that uses it. If you use an inventory, it will be loaded anyway it just needs to be defined.

Comment: Good morning, Kroustou. I have updated my question to hopefully better understand your answers above regarding defining {{ home_user }}.

Thank you again!

Comment: Check this document out: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#tips-on-where-to-set-variables, you dont have to load variables manually, check the getting started documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_getting_started.html

Comment: Thank you, Kroustou! I will read up on this documentation.